# Salesforce Error in validating deployment

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I'm very new to Salesforce so please bear with me.  I'm getting the following error when trying to validate my inbound changeset:

Failure Message: "System.QueryException: No such column 'Address' on entity 'Lead'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.", Failure Stack Trace: "(Zendesk)"

My code passes has adequate test coverage on a sandbox environment but this message just baffles me.

Address field is a standard field for the Lead Entity and non of my code refers to the Address field.

Really at a loss on this one, any help greatly appreciated..

Comment: I couldn't find a solution so ended up uninstalling the Zendesk for Salesforce package which is currently not in use.

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment / validation result should tell you exactly on which file & line it failed. Can you post the relevant bit of code maybe?

`Address` is a beta field (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm) which means that you'd have to contact SF support to give you access to it (maybe you did it in the sandbox but production is another story). It should be safe to identify the class & delete the reference to this field (or use the old address component fields like `City`, `Street`)... A properly unit test wouldn't hardcode a field that might not exist in target org...